# Limit the rows to 20 in solr query but allowing cluster to search between 100 rows ?

Tags: search, solr, clustered-index

I want to display only 20 rows in the solr query. However, I wants the carrot2 cluster to create labels/perform clustering for 100 rows ?. Both the thing should happen in the same query. Is it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Carrot clustering happens dynamically on the number of results fetched by Solr which is controlled by the rows parameter.
So the control of Solr results has to happen on the client side.

You can add clustering as [last-components with request handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent#Configuration) so that the search and clustering can be performed with a single call

e.g config :-

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">text</str>
    <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
    <str name="clustering.engine">default</str>
    <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>

    <!-- Fields to cluster on -->
    <str name="carrot.title">name</str>
    <str name="carrot.snippet">features</str>      
 </lst>
 <arr name="last-components">
   <str>clustering</str>
 </arr>   
</requestHandler>
```

Or with url `clustering=true&clustering.engine=default&clustering.results=true&carrot.title=name&carrot.snippet=features`

Change the title and snippet parameters as per your field mappings

Comment: For clustering url goes like this
http://localhost:8983/solr/clustering?q=bags&rows=100.

And for searching url goes like this:
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=bags&wt=xml&indent=true
Can I invoke/implement both clustering and search/select in same url ?

Comment: I have tried this url in solr :http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=bags&wt=xml&indent=true&clustering=true&clustering.results=true&carrot.title=title
ie. passing parameters of clusters in select statement. But it did not displayed any clusters ?

Comment: did you add clsutering to the last-components in the request handler ? as mentioned in the link.

Comment: yes I have done. when i tried this url http://localhost:8983/solr/clustering?q=*:*&rows=10. It worked fine and it was showing clusters. But I was expecting clusters results to be displayed while I give this url http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=bags&wt=xml&indent=true&clustering=true&clustering.results=true&carrot.title=title, which was not so.

Comment: i was able to get the config running for Solr 4.3.0 example setup with jetty. Config added in the answer.

Comment: I am using Tomcat. I hope my question is clear that while requesting SELECT request handler,I am trying to fetch CLUSTER results by passing carrot2 parameters like carrot.title=fieldname,clusterting.results=true and other parameters.
But still I am not getting any clusters ..

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, configuring the clustering parameters as defaults (you can pass as parameters as well) and adding clustering in the last-components to the request handler and firing the query returns the clusters with the response. I have tested it on Solr 4.3.0. Can you try the examples also can you check if the clusters are returned for all results.

Comment: How to configure clustering parameters as defaults ??. Passing them in url. That I am already doing .Still not results. Can you tell me in url which all parameters you are passing with select request handler to fetch cluster results ?

Comment: Great Mr. Jayendra. It works. Thanks a lot. Can we define two qf in same handler. One for select statement without clusters and other with clusters ?. Is it possible ?

Comment: also, didnt get the multiple qf question. qf is query fields on which the query works and clustering works on the results. so it has to be different queries.

Comment: The earlier post really worked for me. I absolutely agree.But qf is my next question.Suppose I have already defined qf for select handler and now I also calling clusters in the same select handler by passing parameters(example that you gave above).So the qf of select handler is also applicable to clusters results, which I do not desire.I wants to define separate qf for both in same handler. Can we do that ?